# make can't find files on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

I am having a problem using make and makefile on OSX.

My Errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/sduball/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/source/main.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [main.o] Error
```

1. Error only occurs when I use make

   - I have checked that the filepath is valid many times (file does exist)
   - I have run the g++ command by hand on OSX (and it worked)
   - I have been using the same makefile on my Ubuntu desktop perfectly fine
2. This seems to be an error with the variables on my makefile somehow

   - From makefile shown I have tried to make the program w/o the variables in my file recipes, and it works.
   - I have tried using := for my variable declarations but it doesn't work
3. I am very confused because the path that clang spits out as an error is a valid path ( i have tabbed out the path many times and opened the exact path with vim and it works)

The only SO posts I have seen about this issue are realted to xcode projects not finding files after manually moving a project. I have not found anything relating to this specific problem I am having. Thank you in advance for your help.

makefile

```
##### VARIABLES #####
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++14

DIR = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/
SOURCE = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/source/
BUILD = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/build/

##### TARGETS #####
# executable
copy: main.o game.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BUILD)main.o $(BUILD)game.o -lncursesw -o $(DIR)copy

# source
main.o: main.cpp game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)main.cpp -o $(BUILD)main.o

game.o: game.cpp game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)game.cpp -o $(BUILD)game.o
```

Comment: Not the cause of your trouble, but it would probably be better to define: `SOURCE = ${DIR}/source/` and `BUILD = ${DIR}/build/` as you'd then only have to edit or override the value of `DIR` to move the whole system.  Make use of such built-up names whenever it is logically correct.  (I probably wouldn't include the trailing slashes, but that's a separate discussion.)  And if you normally run the build from the `${DIR}` directory, then I'd use `DIR = .` rather than an absolute pathname.

Comment: Writing makefile recipes that don't build the identical file as the target you listed in the rule is a serious make no-no.  That is, all your compile and link lines should be using `-o $@`, never `-o /path/to/some/file`.  Most likely when you make that change make will complain that it doesn't know how to build some things.  THAT is the problem you need to fix.  Also in general it's bad form to embed fully-qualified paths into your makefile: as soon as you need to rename a directory or move this somewhere it will fail.  Use relative paths, only.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You hit the nail on the head, I replaced DIR = . and it works flawlessly. MadScientist now that my $(DIR) is equal to the current directory I believe that resolves the problem of using an absolute path, appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the directory variables in the target/dependency lines, not just the command lines.

```
##### VARIABLES #####
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++14

DIR = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/
SOURCE = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/source/
BUILD = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/build/

##### TARGETS #####
# executable
$(DIR)copy: $(BUILD)main.o $(BUILD)game.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BUILD)main.o $(BUILD)game.o -lncursesw -o $(DIR)copy

# source
$(BUILD)main.o: $(SOURCE)main.cpp $(SOURCE)game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)main.cpp -o $(BUILD)main.o

$(BUILD)game.o: $(SOURCE)game.cpp $(SOURCE)game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)game.cpp -o $(BUILD)game.o
```

Comment: Just tried that and it is giving me another error: make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/sduball/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/build/main.cpp`, needed by `/Users/sduball/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/build/main.o`. Stop.

Comment: Because I am in the same directory as the source files I tried removing the  $(SOURCE) variable references from my recipes, but am getting a similar error that the main.o file cannot be found. It still looks like some kind of an error with the variables.

Comment: I don't believe you're supposed to include the source files on the target line. That's where dependencies go. Shouldn't it just be `$(BUILD)game.o:` and `$(BUILD)main.o` on their own lines then the compile commands?

Comment: @ChillyPenguin672 Do you see that make tries to touch `.../build/main.cpp` instead of `.../source/main.cpp` after your wrong makefile changes? How do you check the file existence, so you are sure that it exists? Try to copy the file path from the error output and use the shell command `file <path>` or similar.

Comment: @Arc676 I believe that it is allowed to add source files to target lines, but not necessary as they are implicitly added to the dependency list. However I don't think there is anything wrong with having them there. At least accoriding to the site I learned the syntax from: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/

Comment: @S.M. It doesn't look like its trying to touch a file, also I have checked the file path by copying into my terminal. I used : vim <copy_error_file> and cd <copy_error_file> and both were successful. The weirdest thing is that the exact same makefile works flawlessly on my Ubuntu desktop. :/

Comment: Ok then. I only point this out because your error message shows that `make` is trying to find rules for building `main.cpp` and can’t find this target in the Makefile.

Comment: @ChillyPenguin672
You did something wrong. cd is not working with files. Please show the output of `ls /Users/sduball/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/source/main.cpp`. It must be the full path from the error message, not a file name. In my previous comment I wanted to notice you that make tries to find `main.cpp` in the `.../build` directory, ithat is wrong.

Comment: @S.M. ok I see what you are saying now, that was my fault. The actual message it was looking for main.cpp in the source file, I had backspaced my SO comment and made a mistake of writing /build/main.cpp when the actual error message was looking for /source/main.cpp.

Comment: So you type the error messages manually, not copy and paste the original messages? It sounds strange.

Answer (score 0):

As per @JonathanLeffler 's comment on the original question I replaced the DIR path with DIR = .

```
DIR = ~/Documents/Programming/Cpp/ncurses_projects/tictactoe/
```

to

```
DIR = .
```

This completely solves the problem. Source code below.

makefile

```
##### VARIABLES #####
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++14

DIR = .
SOURCE = $(DIR)/source
BUILD = $(DIR)/build


##### TARGETS #####
# executable
copy: $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/game.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/game.o -lncursesw -o $(DIR)/copy

# source
main.o: $(SOURCE)/main.cpp $(SOURCE)/game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOUCE)/main.cpp -o $(BUILD)/main.o

game.o: $(SOURCE)/game.cpp $(SOURCE)/game.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)/game.cpp -o $(BUILD)/game.o
```